# Show Recently Viewed Custom Post to the visitor without plugin

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to Show Recently Viewed Custom Posts to the visitor without plugin because my design is different. Can anyone advice me how to achieve this functionality. I'll do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that by using cookies. just create a cookie on init function on single page and create a array inside cookie with time of the visit on the post.
And then you can retrieve the posts according to your design.